# jQuery chamando uma action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou desenvolvendo um web site em ASP.NET MVC que usa jquery para controlar alguns plugins como spinner, toastr e outros. Minha dúvida é se devo chamar a *Action* via jquery para validar o *model* e dentro da *Action* fazer uma chamada rest (que foi construída em web api) e retornar a resposta na função javascript.

Como trabalhei muito com mobile, a maior parte das chamadas eram feitas no cliente, e neste caso vejo que a chamada está sendo feita dentro do *controller*, no caso, no servidor.

Comment: Essa action result não poderia ser um evento no jQuery?

Comment: creio que nao, ela basicamente, valida a model que foi passado via post e  executa uma chamada rest para autenticacao. Caso ok, gera o cookie e o ticket de autenticacao

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o seu cenário, seria algo como um Oauth? Onde o cliente se autênticou previamente em um WebAPI que gerência o acesso à múltiplas aplicações, então ao acessar a aplicação, faz uma requisição a está WebAPI para validar o acesso para então prosseguir?

Comment: Isso mesmo @TobyMosque. Acha que estou fazendo errado? vejo esse mesmo cenario para minhas outras controllers, que precisam fazer o acesso da webapi onde a chamada dos metodos sao feitos na controller

Comment: Acho que está no caminho certo, mas aconselho que crie um custom Action filter para autenticação e coloque toda a sua lógica nele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Minha dúvida é se devo chamar a *Action* via jquery para validar o *model* e dentro da *Action* fazer uma chamada rest (que foi construída em web api) e retornar a resposta na função javascript.

Web API é um lugar ótimo para fazer isso, mas é bom certificar que o cabeçalho da requisição peça explicitamente um JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "json",
    accepts: {
        text: "application/json"
    },
    ...
});
```

Pode ser feito no ASP.NET MVC também, mas não use `ActionResult` para declarar a *Action*. Use:

```
public JsonResult MinhaAction() { ... }
```